# Show Less/Show More button using react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my data, initially I want show only 4 albums on the page, then when a user click on **Show More** I want to load the next 4 albums. And when user click on the **Show Less** button, it goes back to the previous/initial state.

```
    cardData: [
        {
            id: 1,
            img: eight0eightheartbreak,
            title: '808 & Heartbreak',
            desc: 'desc 1'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            img: collegedropout,
            title: 'College Dropout',
            desc: 'desc 2'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            img: graduation,
            title: 'Graduation',
            desc: 'desc 3'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            img: lateregistration,
            title: 'Late Registration',
            desc: 'desc 4'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            img: MBDTF,
            title: 'My Beatiful Dark Twisted Fantesy',
            desc: 'desc 5'
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            img: TLOP,
            title: 'The Life of Pablo',
            desc: 'desc 6'
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            img: Ye,
            title: 'Ye',
            desc: 'desc 7'
        },
        {
            id: 8,
            img: yeezus,
            title: 'Yeezus',
            desc: 'desc 8'
        },
        {
            id: 9,
            img: JIK,
            title: 'Jesus Is King',
            desc: 'desc 9'
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my code

```
    const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);
    const [noOfElements, setnoOfElements] = useState(4);
    const slice = Data.cardData.slice(0, noOfElements);
    const loadMore = ()=>{
        setnoOfElements(noOfElements + 4)
        }
    return (
       <section className="py-4 container">
           <div className="row justify-content-center">

               {slice.map((item, index)=>{
                   return(
                   <div className= "col-11 col-md-6 col-lg-3 max-0 mb-4">
                   <div className="card p-0 overflow-hidden h-100 shadow">
                       <img src={item.img} alt="" className="card-img-top" />
                       <div className="card-body">
                           <h5 className="card-title">{item.title}</h5>
                           <p className="card-text">{item.desc}</p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
                   )
               })}
           </div>
           <button className="btn btn-dark d-block-w-100" onClick={()=>loadMore()} >
           Read more
           </button>
       </section>
    )
}
```

I have managed to create a **Show more** button, now how do I create Show Less button using the same logic, react useState hook? I know how to make it using component, but I want to do it using useState, is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can  just put a conditional tag in your slice.map:

```
{slice.map((item, index)=>{
    if( index <= noOfElements ){
       return <div className= "col-11 col-md-6 col-lg-3 max-0 mb-4">...</div>
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);
    const [noOfElements, setnoOfElements] = useState(4);
    const slice = Data.cardData.slice(0, noOfElements);
    const loadMore = ()=>{
        setnoOfElements(noOfElements + 4)
        }
    const loadLess = ()=>{
      setnoOfElements(noOfElements - 4)
      }
    return (
       <section className="py-4 container">
           <div className="row justify-content-center">

               {slice.map((item, index)=>{
                   return(
                   <div className= "col-11 col-md-6 col-lg-3 max-0 mb-4">
                   <div className="card p-0 overflow-hidden h-100 shadow">
                       <img src={item.img} alt="" className="card-img-top" />
                       <div className="card-body">
                           <h5 className="card-title">{item.title}</h5>
                           <p className="card-text">{item.desc}</p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
                   )
               })}
           </div>
           <button className="btn btn-dark d-block-w-100" onClick={()=>loadMore()} >
           Read more
           </button>
           <button className="btn btn-dark d-block-w-100" onClick={()=>loadLess()} >
           Read less
           </button>
       </section>
    )
```

Is this is you actually needed?

Comment: But they are two different buttons, what if I want to toggle the same button?

Comment: But if it is loaded 8 items and another 8 items are hidden then you need both buttons to hide four and rt?

Comment: you can use the same button, and compare noOfElements and cardData.length.  if it is equal call loadLess otherwise call loadMore

Comment: can't I change the onClick function and the button content conditionally?

Comment: Yes, you can conditionally increment or decrement.  noOfElements in function

Comment: like `onClick={noOfElements==Data.cardsData.length? loadLess:loadMore}` this?

Comment: onClick={noOfElements>=Data.cardsData.length? loadLess:loadMore}

Comment: I am getting an error, **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')**

Comment: please add a screenshot of you implementation and error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237056/discussion-between-javeria-and-sojin).